# Generacion de base de datos Hibernate 5.4

Tags: java, base-de-datos, hibernate

Estoy usando hibernate 5.4 (previamente usaba hibernate 4) y al parecer han cambiado la manera de impactar las clases de java en la base de datos.

Alguien sabe como impactar en la base de datos las clases de java con hibernate 5.4??

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con impactar?

Comment: Con impactar me refiero a generar las tablas en la base de datos a partir de las clases de java.

Answer (score 1):

Para crear tablas usando Hibernate tenemos varias opciones a usar: Hibernate Tools, archivos xml, anotaciones, etc.

Supongamos que quiero crear una Entidad llamada Alumno con cuatro atributos(id, nombre, telefono, fecha).

Con archivos XML tendríamos algo como esto:

**Alumno.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.codes.Alumno" table="Alumno" >
 <id column="Id" name="id" type="integer"/>
 <property name="nombre" column="nombre" />
 <property name="telefono" column="telefono" />
 <property name="fecha" column="fecha" />
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Y la clase **Alumno.java**

```
package com.codes.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.time.LocalDate;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Alumno implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @Getter @Setter public int id;
    @Getter @Setter public String nombre;
    @Getter @Setter public String telefono; 
    @Getter @Setter public LocalDate fecha;
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/curso</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- archivo de mapeo -->
        <mapping resource="Alumno.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Con anotaciones(@) mi clase **Alumno.java** se vería así:

```
package com.codes.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name="alumno")
@Entity(name="Alumno")
public class Alumno implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526472295622776147L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Getter @Setter public int id;
    @Column(name="nombre")
    @Getter @Setter public String nombre;
    @Column(name="telefono")
    @Getter @Setter public String telefono; 
    @Column(name="fecha")
    @Getter @Setter public LocalDate fecha;
}
```

Además de no olvidar el archivo **hibernate.cfg.xml** para ambos casos:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/curso</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- clase con anotaciones --->
        <mapping class="org.codes.Alumno" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Links:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/
http://hibernate.org/tools/

https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/hibernate/generator-classes-in-hibernate.html
http://www.cursohibernate.es/doku.php?id=unidades:02_hibernate:02_entidad